# Regex: Extract http and title attributes from anchor tag with PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a bunch of URLs structured like so

```
<h4 class="classname"><a href="http://some-website.com" onclick="someVaryingJS();" title="Some Title">Some Title</a><h4>
```

I want to be able to extract just the href and title attributes, keeping in mind the onclick attribute changes per tag and that I only want to do it for anchor tags that are within h4's of that class.

Comment: You want to use some DOM tool for this, not regex ;)

Comment: A DOM parser might be a better bet for this. Esp if the structure isn't set (i.e. if other tags could be allowed in the `<h4>`)

Comment: @iamthejeff : To extend nikic's suggestion, try jQuery :)

Comment: Don't forget XHTML is a big XML document. Not sure about PHP but in .NET if the XHTML is well formed, you could use XML libraries to write XPATH expressions to find all <a> tags within <h4> tags and from them, get attribute values. Good luck

Comment: I should have mentioned I am scraping a site to get the tags (legit intentions!), so unfortunately any kind of client-side processing won't work for this

Comment: @Michael Mao: Obviously the OP is interested in a PHP solution. Why suggest jQuery?

Comment: PHP has DOM, too (DOMDocument). That's nothing specific to JavaScript.

Comment: @Felix Kling: sorry I thought it referred to client-side DOM tool, obviously my understanding's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load the html fragment into [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php), and process it from there..?

It's obviously going to be more flexible, but a lot heavier than a straight up regex.